# Why won't IE ask to save my login details for certain sites?

Tags: internet-explorer, passwords

When I log in to certain sites, IE won't ask me if I want to save my username and password. One example is some bank account sites.

- Why doesn't it ask if I want it to remember my password? Is it the bank configuring the site so IE doesn't ask?
- How can I override the setting so IE does in fact ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes. There is a custom [autocomplete HTML attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486%28VS.85%29.aspx) that allows page author to turn autocompletion off. Also if both of the following conditions are true:

   1. The page was delivered over HTTPS
   2. The page was delivered with headers or a META tag that prevents caching

   autocompletion will be turned off too.
2. Apparently there is no way to do this with Internet Explorer standard settings. Maybe some external password manager like [Roboform](http://www.roboform.com/) (or any free alternative) can solve this issue.